# Play 2.0 @routes.Assets.at within code loaded using @Html()

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0, eval, assets

I'm populating a model (Page) whereby one of its String attributes (content) contains Scala template code:

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/image.gif")" alt="alt text" />
```

In my Scala template I pass in the model:

```
@(page: models.Page)
@Html(page.getContent())
```

As expected, @routes.Assets.at isn't resolved to the assets path.

1. Is there an eval() type utility function in Play 2.0 to serve this purpose?
2. Or, can I derive the actual path represented by the assets route from within the controller? I would then subsequently perform a String replace

EDIT - to provide more context:

Controller code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Page page = new Page();
// TODO: request().uri() mapping to json resource
File x = Play.current().getFile("/content/index.json");
try {
    page = mapper.readValue(x, Page.class);
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    return notFound();
}
```

Model code:

```
public void setContent(String content) {
    // TODO: replace to resolve assets route
    this.content = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(content);
}
```

Appreciate any solution or comments on approach.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you resolve the route BEFORE passing to the template?

Comment: As per point two. I presume this would happen from within the controller. But how?

Comment: In the controller code where you evaluate the string, you could do it as an XML literal: `<img src={routes.Assets.at("images/image.gif")} />`

Comment: That's it! Thanks. I actually did it on the model setter which appears to work:
this.content = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(content).replaceAll("###ASSETS_FOLDER###", routes.Assets.at("").url());

Thanks both - I'll accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should realize one basic thing: you **do not need** to use `@routes.Assets.at()` at all - it's just a helper, but has no special meaning. So just put resolved path in your code:

```
 <img src="/assets/images/image.gif" alt="alt text" />
```

If you really, really want to keep the possibility of dynamic paths use own marker in the code, which you can easily replace `replace()` method:

```
 <img src="###ASSETS_FOLDER###/images/image.gif" alt="alt text" />
```

(of course that's a default location, change it if you have other)

Comment: Yes - I might have to resort to that. But it would be nice to have a single place to change this value in keeping with the spirit of things :)

Comment: ach, my bad; of course by default it's `/assets/` not `/public/` I'm sorry, fixed.

Comment: ok, but let's say I want to set/change the assets path from within the routes file only. i.e. avoiding any hard coded/duplicate paths in the model/controller/elsewhere.